# Javascript + Click all divs

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I trying to have a javascript function to click all divs that has an id of 'divResults' in my form but apparently it doesn't work, no errors but nothing buldges. Please advice. Thanks.

```
 <a href="javascript:clickAllDivs()">Expand All</a>  |  <a href="javascript:clickAllDivs()" >Collapse All</a>
```

JavaScript :

```
     function clickAllDivs() {
                         var els = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
                         var i = els.length; while (i--)
                             if (els[i].id == 'divResults' ) {
                             //alert("I am in"); //Check if div is eating this function
                             els[i].click();
                         }
                     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are a couple of problems, first, you should have only one element with an id of divResults in your page, ids are unique.

To find an element with a particular id, you can do:

```
var el = document.getElementById('divResults');
```

If you want more elements, try using a class, and checking by `className` in your loop, like:

```
while (i--) {
if (els[i].className == 'yourClassName' ) {
     //code
   }
}
```

Second, calling `els[i].click();` means that you have setted a property on that element with the name of click and assigned it a function. 
If you had done that, then the code is right, if not check how are you binding the event, for example if you're doing

```
document.getElementById('divResults').onclick = function(){};  //bind click event
```

then you should do

```
els[i].onclick();
```

You can also use jQuery for doing this in a really simple way, info [here](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about `id`.

- **`id` is *unique***. There can only be *one* element with a specific `id`, which is why your code isn't going to work fundamentally.

You are probably looking for `class`, not `id`.

Read [this article](http://css-tricks.com/818-the-difference-between-id-and-class/) for more info about the differences between the two.

---

As for your *current* error, `.click()` isn't a native JavaScript function, if I am remembering correctly. Are you using a JavaScript library like jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

First off, this doesn't make any sense because you're only supposed to have one object in a page with a given ID, yet you're trying to find all the objects with the same ID.

If you really want to find multiple elements, then I'd suggest you use a common class name for the desired elements.

Secondly, the `.click()` method is not available on div elements in all browsers.  For example, it was only implemented for all elements in Firefox in version 5.  It would be better to factor your code into a function that operates on the click and then just call the function directly (rather than trying to simulate a click) passing it the desired object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `element.dispatchEvent` method... but i don't think its supported in all the browsers.

Check this link,
[element.dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent)

---

In jquery though you have the `trigger` method which basically calls all the listers, but does't really perform the click action.

```
$('#divResults').trigger('click')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function clickItem(divObj) { 
                if (divObj.click) { 
                    divObj.click() 
                } else if(document.createEvent) { 
                    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");  
                    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,  
                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);  
                    var allowDefault = divObj.dispatchEvent(evt);
                }
            }

            function clickAllDivs() {
                var els = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
                var i = els.length;
                while (i--)
                    // you'll need to keep id unique
                    if (els[i].id.indexOf('divResults') == 0) {
                        //alert("I am in"); //Check if div is eating this function
                        clickItem(els[i]);
                    }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:clickAllDivs();">Expand All</a>  |  <a href="javascript:clickAllDivs()" >Collapse All</a>
        <div id="divResults1" onclick="alert('this was clicked through code');">Div to click</div>
        <div id="divResults2" onclick="alert('this was also clicked through code');">Div to click</div>
    </body>
</html>
```